# What do you call a certificate that a doctor gives you so that you could submit it to your employer as proof that were sick?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

What do you call a certificate that a doctor gives you so that you could submit it to your employer as proof that were sick?

Please, name your part of the world (country, county, etc.)

Comment: I live in Canada (Ontario); I've usually just heard "doctor's note", though that was if you're late for school for example, and need to excuse it as a legitimate cause for lateness/absence, and it doesn't matter if it was illness or just any appointment. "Proof of illness" and "proof of sickness" both seem to be fine as far as I know in a formal context for submitting to an employer for sick leave.

Comment: I'm in NYC, and @hyper-neutrino 's answer is equally valid for me, even today (I'm a civil servant with limited "sick leave").

Comment: Informally I've often heard it referred to as a **sick note**.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, a certificate from a doctor supporting sickness absence from work is formally called a 'medical certificate'. For most of my life people called them 'sick notes' but in 2010 they were officially restyled 'fit notes' or 'statements of fitness to work'. The emphasis shifted from how long you would be 'sick' to when you would be fit. A fit note allows the doctor  to identify one of two options and specify a time period (e.g. a week/month, or until a specific date): (1) not fit for work, (2) may be fit for work. This change (sick note to fit note) has been adopted by some doctors in Australia, and discussion has happened in New Zealand.